# Invalid Sender when Using Quorum

Tags: transactions, quorum

I followed this tutorial (https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/From-Scratch) to start up Quorum with 4 nodes using istanbul consensus. The nodes can connect and blocks are being generated but I cannot add transactions as I always get "Error: invalid sender undefined" for any type of transaction I want to add (e.g. new contract creation or ether transfer).

For example if I "geth attach new-node-2/geth.ipc" into my second node and I unlock its main account so that

```
> personal.listWallets
[{
    accounts: [{
        address: "0x5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4",
        url: "keystore:///home/.../Node2/new-node-2/keystore/UTC--2019-03-29T15-24-11.813787559Z--5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4"
    }],
    status: "Unlocked",
    url: "keystore:///home/.../Node2/new-node-2/keystore/UTC--2019-03-29T15-24-11.813787559Z--5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4"
}]
```

And I perform any transaction, then I get an error like so:

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4', to: '0x952e0ce2a4bf5e9dbbd5e186b03f760fa25d3278', value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
Error: invalid sender
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Note that my files are arranged:

```
.../Node2$ ls
genesis.json  new-node-2  node.log  nohup.out

.../Node2$ ls new-node-2/
geth
geth.ipc
keystore
nodekey
permissioned-nodes.json
static-nodes.json

.../Node2$ ls new-node-2/keystore
UTC--2019-03-29T15-24-11.813787559Z--5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4
```

While all nodes share the same genesis.json, permissioned-nodes.json and static-nodes.json file. The genesis.json file being:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 20,
        "eip150Block": 1,
        "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "eip155Block": 1,
        "eip158Block": 1,
        "byzantiumBlock": 1,
        "istanbul": {
            "epoch": 30000,
            "policy": 0
        },
        "isQuorum": true
    },
    "nonce": "0x0",
    "timestamp": "0x5c9e3793",
    "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f89af854947f2fb27d5bf950b3845e6a83161afcae1cf0823e94d7427ce2ebdbfbcf9a80c628df51af118faea25894965d1690307a389e5ac9c3a2abc6972786e01f8194d2209c0a0549cf4458764bf11433a6fe4054c730b8410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0",
    "gasLimit": "0xe0000000",
    "difficulty": "0x1",
    "mixHash": "0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
        "7f2fb27d5bf950b3845e6a83161afcae1cf0823e": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "965d1690307a389e5ac9c3a2abc6972786e01f81": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "d2209c0a0549cf4458764bf11433a6fe4054c730": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "d7427ce2ebdbfbcf9a80c628df51af118faea258": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "6f42aa5c4b9ca57d264395f4eaa8b653bb83047e": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "5449199af0e2c3d59b35ebabb926a2dae6e2fba4": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        },
        "6aa89d734ea689c05baa5833459e768dfb6cb54d": {
            "balance": "0x446c3b15f9926687d2c40534fdb564000000000000"
        }
    },
    "number": "0x0",
    "gasUsed": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

And all nodes are on the same  network, i.e. the following holds for all nodes:

```
> admin.nodeInfo.protocols.istanbul.network
20
```

Comment: Note that "geth version new-node-2/geth.ipc" gives
Geth
Version: 1.7.2-stable
Git Commit: 43424382f29ec3472941fa9de014a41344e5ec55
Quorum Version: 2.0.2
Architecture: amd64
Network Id: 1 
Go Version: go1.10.3
Operating System: linux
Notice that the network Id is different to "admin.nodeInfo.protocols.istanbul.network" , is this a clash of ethereum and quorum geth on the same PC?

Answer (score 0):

Note that I solved this issue by analysing the Quorum 7-node example and realising that the config section of the genesis file needs to have

```
"eip150Block": 2,
       "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
       "eip155Block": 0,
       "eip158Block": 3,
       "byzantiumBlock": 1,
       "istanbul": {
           "epoch": 30000,
           "policy": 0
       },
       "isQuorum": true
```

but istanbul setup generates different numbers. Note that I am not sure exactly what parameter not allows me to add transactions but it is one of the above. This issue can be tracked here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/670

Answer (score 0):

istanbul-tools is generic for ethereum, so it doesn't generate a genesis specific to quorum, and some hand-crafting is expected. For example, the 'isQuorum' flag has to be added. Taking a istanbul-genesis.json copy from quorum-examples is a good solution.
Having said that, I just generated a genesis.json using istanbul-tools and it worked fine with quorum. The only change I had to make was to change extraData to have the correct validator node addresses.